# File not rendering in freestyle properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, text-object, path, freestyle

So this is my file:

[image]

And  this is how it's rendering:
[image]

I don't know any way of fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved the line at the bottom down:
[image]

[image]

Comment: which line exactly do you mean?

Comment: The one you see at the bottom of the render (right) on the first image. Also it is the text not line I wrote that wrong

Comment: You mean the one next to 'Wedding' ?

Comment: The one next to Pradesh in the first Image I posted